# logstash parse with offline logs will give better performance or online?

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-4, logstash-configuration

I have ELK stack installed and about to do performance testing.
Getting below doubt which am not able to resolve myself, expertise suggestions/opinions would be helpful.

I am doubtful on,

**1.**  whether to do logstash on LIVE - meaning, install logstash and run ELK in parallel with my performance testing on application.

**2.** Or First do the performance testing collect logs and feed logs to logstash offline. (this option is very much possible, as am running this test for about 30minutes only)

Which will b better performant ?

My application is on Java and since logstash also uses JVM for its parsing, am afraid it will have impact on my application performance.
Considering this, I prefer to go with option 2 , but would like to know are there any benefits/advantages going with option 1 that am missing ??

Help/suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Test your *real* environment under *real* conditions to get anything meaningful.

Will you run logstash on the server? Or will you feed your logs in the background to i.e. Kafka as described in my [blogpost](http://blog.mmlac.com/how-to-pre-process-logs-with-logstash/) you summoned me from? Or will you run a batch job and then after the fact collect the logs?

Of course doing anything on the server itself during processing will have an impact and also tuning your JVM will have a big influence on how well everything performs. In general it is not an issue to run multiple JVMs on the same server.

Do your tests once with logstash / kafka / flume or any other log processing or shipping tool you want to use enabled and then run a second pass without these tools to get an idea of *how much* they impact the performance.